# make the first part of a text area readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea element in html like this:

```
<textarea id="txtarea">some text</textarea>
```

I want the user to be able to add text to the text area but to make 'some text' readonly/not editable.

I this is the closest I have got to a solution with jquery:

```
$('#txtarea').text[0]('t');
$('#txtarea').text[0]('x'); //etc
```

this is not working because text0 is not a syntax error. 
does somebody know how to change the first words of a text area or mabye provide another solution I didnt think about? Thanks
EDIT:

I don't want only a default text area text, but that it will be uneresable

Comment: A similiar question is found here [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th)

Comment: I've put on of the answers in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vkx9bg)

Comment: It’s “not a syntax error”? Really? Also, is readonly text user-entered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a default text to the beginning of an html text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846041/how-do-i-add-a-default-text-to-the-beginning-of-an-html-text-area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend is to add a function on `keyup` which checks the `.val()` for the presence of the `.text()`. If it is not found, set the `.val()` *equal* to the `.text()`. Because the `.text()` is set on page load, and the `.val()` is updated as you type, this way you'll be able to add new text to the `<textarea>`, but it will always add back in the original text if it is removed.

This can be seen in the following, where the user is free to type new text, but if the `<textarea>` doesn't contain the string `some text`, the `<textarea>` will be updated to contain it:

```js
$('#txtarea').on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).val().indexOf($(this).text()) === -1) {
    $(this).val($(this).text());
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="txtarea">some text</textarea>
```

Comment: I suggest you make it so that it doesnt delete the new input if the original text is modified.

Comment: It works until someone select the text, click with right button and click "cut" or use right click to paste another text over the one that is setted

Comment: that was good enough for me and fixed what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can´t really keep an user from editing the text within the textarea. It would also be confusing (don't really know your use-case).

You could maybe use TWO textareas, one, for the *existing* text (which is readonly) another, for the *new* text.

Another aproach, if you reaaally want to have all in the same textarea, is to keep the *old* text in a variable, then, when the use exits the textarea (blur event), make sure that the *new* text *begins with* the *old* text. If it doesn´t then do whatever (reset to old text, return focus to control, etc)